How to setup global proxy for Node.js?
I have trouble with "@supabase/supabase-js" https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/30490 and periodically have similar troubles with various other libraries. There are only one way to investigate similar issues - look to details communication between Node.JS libraries and servers.
I found two packages 'global-tunnel-ng' and 'node-global-proxy' and try to investigate communication between Node and server with Fiddler reverse proxy, but failed. Fiddler captures any traffic, but can not captured Node traffic (except simple Fetch request), for example library "@supabase/supabase-js" mysteriously working by another way and not used Fiddler proxy server what I defined in Fiddler and with 'global-tunnel-ng' or 'node-global-proxy'.
What correct way to forbid any Node.JS fluent internet communication without my Proxy server setting?
